# how to elegant pass value from controller to service and get value from service in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, service, controller

I am a newer in Java and SpringBoot. I'm currently developing a simple Spring Boot project， and I used the controller-service-dao as my backend logic. So, what is the recommended way to pass values from controller to service? And the elegant to get service return value?

one of my controller method below :

```
@GetMapping("/getAllFunctionTables")
public Result<Object> getAllFunctionTables(@RequestParam String projectKey) {
        try {
            int projectId = CommonUtils.extractNumber(projectKey);
            List<Map<String, String>> results = functionService.getAllFunctionTables(projectId);
            return Result.ok(results, "Get Functon Table");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Result.fail("Error, No Function Table");
    }
```

and the service is:
(use mybatis-plus to manipulate databases)

```
public List<Map<String, String>> getAllFunctionTables(Integer projectId) {
        QueryWrapper<FunctionTable> queryWrapper = new QueryWrapper<>();
        queryWrapper.eq("project_id", projectId);
        // get function tables 
        List<FunctionTable> functionTables = functionTableMapper.selectList(queryWrapper);
        List<Map<String, String>> results = new ArrayList<>();

        functionTables.forEach(functionTable -> {
            Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<>();
            temp.put("tableKey", String.valueOf(functionTable.getId()));
            temp.put("name", functionTable.getName());
            results.add(temp);
        });

        return results;
    }
```

I don't think this is a good way to maintain and extend code, but I don't know how to optimise that. Any recommendations are good. Thanks!